# Problems using stix2 and bm

Tags: fonts, bold, stix, bm, stix2

I am using the `stix2` package with the `bm` package. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\abcABC}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\mathcal{\abcABC} \\
&\bm{\mathcal{\abcABC}}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
&\mathscr{\abcABC} \\
&\bm{\mathscr{\abcABC}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

And its output:

[image]

where I get the following errors

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/m/n' tried instead on input line 15
.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/m/n' tried instead on input line 15
.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/m/n' tried instead on input line 15
.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 22
.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 22
.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 22
.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/it' tried instead on input line 2
2.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <7.5> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/it' tried instead on input line 2
2.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <6> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/it' tried instead on input line 2
2.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/m/n' tried instead on input line 2
2.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/m/n' tried instead on input line 2
2.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/m/n' tried instead on input line 2
2.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/m/n' tried instead on input line 22
.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/m/n' tried instead on input line 22
.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/m/n' tried instead on input line 22
```

Obviously, the `mathcal` symbols are not bold. But the shown warnings are not limited to this case, it is enough to call either`\bm\mathcal` or `\bm\mathscr`.

### My Questions

1. Is it possible to get a bold `\mathcal`
2. Are those warnings actually problematic? Or can they be ignored without much worry?

**Edit 1:**
I removed `amsfont`, problem stays the same.

**Edit 2:**
The question about the missing bold font of `\mathcal` was answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648622/195313). So the only remaing question is regarding the warnings shown above. Note that those warnings do not depent on the missing bold face of `\mathcal` since the following raises the exact same warnings:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\abcABC}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\bm{\mathscr{\abcABC}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**Final Edit:**
I close this question. Question 1 was already [answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648622/195313) and i [reformulated the second question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648668/195313) in a clearer way.

Comment: you have loaded both stix2 and amsfonts you need to choose one or the other.

Comment: stix2 does not have a bold font so `\boldmath` doesn't do much and so `\bm` can not do much either, it does howevr have bold script `\mathbfscr` but not a bold version of `\mathcal`

Comment: I just removed ``amsfont``, did not change anything.

Comment: Okey, so only ``stix`` but not ``stix2`` has a bold font for ``\matcal``. But it should have a bold version of ``\matscr``, am i correct? Because it throws the above warnings even when only calling ``\bm{\matscr{\abcABC}}}``.

Comment: This would answer question 1, ``stix2`` does not offer a bold ``\matcal`` :-)

Comment: You need `\mathbfscr `  with an `h` and without `\bm`  sitix and stix2 have the same set of bold characters as far as I can see, so the answr is the same for either package

Comment: Yea, sorry for misspelling, happend a few times, but in the example i always had the ``h`` ^^. And no, it is not the same, if i run the exact same example from above, but replace ``stix2`` with ``stix`` i get no warnings (and a bold version of ``\mathcal``). Note that there are two problems: (1) no bold version of ``\mathcal``  in ``stix2``, but ``stix2`` does not provide any bold version, so this is the expected behavior. (2) I get the above warnings independently from ``\mathcal`` and even without calling ``\bm\mathcal`` at all, so this is probably not related to the missing bold font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the type 1 version of `stix2` does not support bold calligraphic, the OTF font, in `unicode-math`, supports `\mathbfcal`.

There is one wrinkle: by default, Unicode maps `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` to the same alphabet.  If you need both in the same document, you must override one or the other, using `\setmathfont[range=`....  In this particular OTF font, the documentation shows that STIX Two Math uses `\mathcal` and `\mathbfcal` as the default, but also has glyphs for `\mathscr` and `\mathbfscr` as Stylistic Set 1.  Thus:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={scr,bfscr}, StylisticSet=1]

\newcommand{\abcABC}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\mathcal{\abcABC} \\
&\mathbfcal{\abcABC}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
&\mathscr{\abcABC} \\
&\mathbfscr{\abcABC}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two Math sample]

An alternative is to load a calligraphic font that does come in bold, with `mathalpha`, such as the set from STIX 1.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage[cal=stixplain]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\abcABC}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\mathcal{\abcABC} \\
&\mathbfcal{\abcABC}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
&\mathscr{\abcABC} \\
&\mathbfscr{\abcABC}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX 2 + stix-plain calligraphic sample]

However, this only works in XeLaTeX.  If you try to compile this with PDFLaTeX, you will get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal
```

This is because legacy TeX allows only sixteen math alphabets, and the `stix2` package already uses them all.

One possible workaround for this is to define your four script/calligraphic alphabets as separate math versions, which is allowed.  You could also switch to text mode and invoke `\usefont`.

If, however, you don't need all the symbols of the full `stix2` package, you might load `mathalpha` with both a `cal=` and a `scr=` option.

Comment: The second mentioned approach (i did not try the ``unicode-math``) worked for replacing the ``\mathcal`` font with a a one that has access to a bold version. But i still get the same warnings as above.

Comment: @moro11 Those warnings say that that particular 8-bit page of the legacy font doesn’t come in a bold version. If you’re trying to use any symbols from it with `\boldsymbol` or `\boldmath`, that could be a problem. If you’re not using it because you changed `\mathcal` to some other font, it shouldn’t be.

Comment: I reformulated my question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648668/195313