# stix2 throws "LaTeX Font Warning" with boldsymbol (or bm)

Tags: fonts, bold, stix

I have the following two MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\mathbfscr{A}$
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{\mathscr{A}}$
\end{document}
```

while both produce a boldface script `A` as expected, the letter throws a bunch of warnings, namely

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/it' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <7.5> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/it' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <6> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/it' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font) Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
```

Why does one raise all those warnings, and the other not? In `stix2.sty` the alphabets are defined as follows:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}      {LS1}{stix2scr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont    {symbols}{bold}{LS1}{stix2scr}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathscr}{symbols}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfscr} {LS1}{stix2scr}{b}{n}
```

As i would understand, the `\mathbfscr` links to `{LS1}{stix2scr}{b}{n}` and `\boldsymbol` uses the `bold` mode of `\mathscr` which links to `{LS1}{stix2scr}{b}{n}`. So in my opinion, those two should be exactly the same, but obviously they are not. What is the difference? And why are they not the same?

Bonus question: I only used the bold form of `\mathscr` in on size, why do all the other warnings to all kinds of alphabets and different font sizes appear, i never tried to use those?

Comment: isn't this the same as your previous three questions!

Comment: Yea, sorry for that, i should have thought in forehand a bit more and do not mix two questions into one. But i had the feeling that most answers got hooked up upon ``\mathcal``, so i though i rephrase the question without even mentioning it. Sorry for bothering and thank you for all the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically explained in answers to your previous questions but I'll try to explain a different way here.

Firstly note that `\boldsymbol{x}` is essentially `\text{\boldmath$x$}` so it locally switches *all* math fonts at all of `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle` sizes to bold, so as previously noted `stix2` defines a lot of fonts almost all of them not available in bold, so you get warnings.

Ultimately the reason is that the Stix Two OpenType math font is not available in bold, if you try your test file with `unicode-math` you get:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\ifx\directlua\undefinded
\usepackage{stix2}
\else
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
\fi
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\boldmath
$\mathscr{A}$
\end{document}
```

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/StixTwoMath(1)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/StixTwoMath(1)/m/n' instead on input line 13.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/StixTwoMath(2)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/StixTwoMath(2)/m/n' instead on input line 13.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/StixTwoMath(3)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/StixTwoMath(3)/m/n' instead on input line 13.
```

`StixTwoMath` OpenType font has thousands of characters. For pdftex the `stix2` package splits it up into multiple fonts of 256 characters each so you get warned about more fonts but essentially exactly the same issue.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/m/n' tried instead on input line 13
.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/m/n' tried instead on input line 13
.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS2/stix2ex/m/n' tried instead on input line 13
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix2-type1/ls1stix2frak.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix2-type1/ls1stix2bb.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 13
.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 13
.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/n' tried instead on input line 13
.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/it' tried instead on input line 1
3.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/it' tried instead on input line 1
3.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/b/it' in size <6> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS1/stix2bb/m/it' tried instead on input line 1
3.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix2-type1/ls2stix2cal.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/m/n' tried instead on input line 1
3.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/m/n' tried instead on input line 1
3.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS2/stix2cal/m/n' tried instead on input line 1
3.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix2-type1/ls1stix2sf.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix2-type1/ls2stix2tt.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/m/n' tried instead on input line 13
.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <7.5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/m/n' tried instead on input line 13
.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font)              Font shape `LS2/stix2tt/m/n' tried instead on input line 13
```

Note for both luatex and pdftex the warnings are at the `\boldmath` (hidden in `\boldsymbol` in your original) setting up all the fonts for bold math so you get the warnings even if you do not use the characters.

Normally `\bm` avoids the costs of `\boldsymbol` switching the entire math version by adding bold fonts as additional fonts in the normal math version, but as previously noted, `stix2` uses a lot of fonts so there are no free slots, so `\bm` falls back to `\boldsymbol` but there are no bold fonts for stix so you get warned of that.

lualatex and xelatex can modify fonts "on the fly" producing a bold font, so if (as suggested in comments by @Davislor) You also set up a bold font:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\ifx\directlua\undefinded
\usepackage{stix2}
\else
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[version=bold, FakeBold=1.2]
\fi
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\boldmath
$\mathscr{A}$
\end{document}
```

Then the document is processed by lualatex without any font warnings.

Comment: The feature-test here might be `\iftutex`. rather than checking for `\directlua`. Both `unicode-math` and `FakeBold=` work in either LuaTeX or XeTeX.

Comment: @Davislor yes old habits, even though `\iftutex` was my idea:-)

Comment: Thank you! Perfect! Thats the answer i was looking for! ``\boldsymbol`` uses ``\boldmath`` to switch the whole environment to bold and hence it tries to bolden all math alphabets in all font sizes. Thank you also for the additional explanation regarding ``bm``!. Interestingly enough, using ``sitx`` instead of ``stix2`` both of my original MWE examples work without warnings.

Comment: @moro11 I'll trace what stix1 is doing later (out of time today)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I seem to recall (could be misremembering) that the difference is that `stix` has more bold alphabets than `stix2`.

Comment: @Davislor Yes, you are right, this is most likely the reason. ``stix`` provides more (probably all?) fonts in bold.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error the first time you use a symbol from `\mathversion{bold}`.  It states that the definitions of the `bold` math version for certain alphabets are invalid.  It’s a bug in the package.  For example, this also triggers it:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\boldmath\(x\)
\end{document}
```

And removing `\boldmath` removes the warnings.

Using `unicode-math` cuts the Gordian knot of legacy 8-bit font formats from last century.  I’d recommend you do that when you can and work around these issues in PDFTeX when you have to.

Comment: it is not a bug in the package, the warnings are correct and the package documentation shows most symbols are not available in bold. there is no bold stix2 opentype either so using unicode-math won't help here

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What’s a bug in the package is that the non-working commands that do nothing but generate those warnings are there at all. There could be a reason for them that I'm overlooking, though.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The specific bold alphabet the OP was looking for, `\mathbfcal`, *is* in the Unicode font but not the legacy package, and the rest can be approximated if needed with `\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[version=bold, FakeBold=1.2]`.

Comment: bfscr is available (and used), but `\boldmath` switches the entire math font set so you get warned about all fonts declared even if not used.

Comment: I could borrow your FakeBold suggestion and add it to my answer, though if you don't mind...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Right, and `\boldsymbol` (as defined in `amsbsy.sty`) calls the bold math version. Which is the reason the bug appears with `\boldsymbol{\mathscr{...}}` but not `\mathbfscr`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And no, i don’t mind at all.