# Why is the STIX2 bold math font not being used here?

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math, boldmath, stix2

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{v}$
\end{document}
```

My MWE above, when compiled with `lualatex` yields a PDF which shows "Fonts" under "Properties" as shown in the attached image:[image]

Why am I not seeing the STIX Two Math fonts instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked directly in the log file not just what lualatex writes to the console? Also are you sure `\mathbf{v}` is the correct syntax under `unicode-math`? `x^2` works fine for me and is in Stix2Math. But `\mathbf{v}` does not work. Using `\symbf` instead of `\mathbf` seems to work.

Comment: `Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "STIXTwoMath/B" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).` seems relevant from the `.log` file. Is the suggestion to use `\symbf` instead of `\mathbf` documented anywhere?

Comment: Not related to this bug, but: You don’t want to load `fonstpec` with the `no-math` option if you also load `unicode-math`. The latter loads `fontspec` automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `unicode-math` (as in classic pdflatex) sets up `mathbf` to use the bold Roman *text* font, which is Noto Serif here.

You can use `\symbf` when it will use 
the bold math upright from Stix Two math.  Or define `\mathbf` to be an alias for `\symbf`

There is no Stix Two Bold Math font (Stix Two Text does have bold)

Comment: Although it would be possible to declare `\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[version=bold, FakeBold=1.2]` and use it with `\boldmath` or `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: @Davislor yes I have an answer somewhere doing just that I suppose I should add a link.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648668/stix2-throws-latex-font-warning-with-boldsymbol-or-bm/648686#648686

Comment: If you’re updating, also worth mentioning that if your existing source consistently uses `\mathbf` for upright math symbols, and not words in math mode, `\usepackage[mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}` is the quickest fix. For new documents, better to use `\symbf` as you suggest, or semantic markup such as a `\vsym{v}` command.

Comment: Thank you @Davislor. I have begun reading the `unicode-math` documentation more carefully and started to understand both the freedom and complexity of the available options.